# Skipping WHERE statement if the variable for that statement is null

Tags: sql-server-2008

I will have a table

```
TABLE1
ID  Name   Country
1   Anna   Singapore
2   Brad   UK
3   Cassie US

declare @place varchar(20);
set @place='US';

select * from Table1 where country=@place;
```

what if the value is `@place` is null???

then, the select will not select anything..

what I want is to treat as there is no where statement for country. while if there's other where statements, they will work..

Any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this simple case in your question just use

```
IF ( @place IS NULL )
  SELECT *
  FROM   table1
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  country = @place
```

If your actual situation is more complex you could use

```
select * 
from Table1 
where @place is null or country=@place 
option (recompile)
```

The reason for needing the `recompile` hint is to avoid having a single plan catering for both cases and doing an unnecessary scan in the event that you do supply an explicit value.

These, and other alternatives such as generating the query dynamically, are discussed in detail in the article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Oh.. conditioning the variable is the only way?? coz.. I dun want to add an if condition statement coz.. the code below is too complicated to add an additional statement.. any other way?

Comment: There isn't an `If` condition statement in my answer.

Comment: i mean in the link.. u provided... inside the link, there's 2 version. the older version is checking with if statement. the newer one is with '%'..

Comment: Yes breaking it into 2 cases with `IF ... ELSE` will mean both end up with good plans and you avoid the `RECOMPILE` overhead but if you read further you'll see the article discusses other methods of achieving the result specifically for situations where you want to avoid this due to number of combinations etc.

Answer (score 1):

`like` and `=` are equivalent in your situation because you are dealing with text (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar) values.

Instead of

```
WHERE  country = @place
```

try

```
WHERE  country like @place
```

For the variable set try
Instead of

```
set @place='US'
```

Try

```
set @country = isnull('''US''','''%''')
```

To test this:

```
declare @country nvarchar(50)
set @country = isnull('''US''','''%''')
print @Country
set @country = isnull(NULL,'''%''')
print @Country
```

The extra quotes are necessary because in your example you are using explicit values - `'` is an escape character and you need a single quote around each value to signify it is NOT a table column. If you were using the COLUMN_NAME you would simply use a single quote around the % character.

Depending on your SQL version you may have to use a different wildcard character.
This is fairly a fairly direct and linear solution, although there are risks associated with open variables.